# ArgoCD ApplicationSet: List not being applied properly

Tags: kubernetes, argocd

I want to deploy using App of Apps pattern

I have my root defined as

```
apiVersion: argoproj.io/v1alpha1
kind: Application
metadata:
  name: example-root
  namespace: argocd
  finalizers:
  - resources-finalizer.argocd.argoproj.io
spec:
  destination:
    namespace: example
    server: https://kubernetes.default.svc
  project: default
  source:
    path: apps
    repoURL: repourl
    targetRevision: HEAD
  syncPolicy:
    automated:
      prune: true
      selfHeal: true
```

In one of the apps I have defined as

```
apiVersion: argoproj.io/v1alpha1
kind: Application
metadata:
  name: example-app
  namespace: argocd
  finalizers:
  - resources-finalizer.argocd.argoproj.io
spec:
  project: default
  source:
    repoURL: {{ .Values.spec.source.repoURL }}
    path: exampleapp
    targetRevision: {{ .Values.spec.source.targetRevision }}
    helm:
      valueFiles:
        - 1.yaml
        - 2.yaml
        - 3.yaml
  destination:
    server: {{ .Values.spec.destination.server }}
    namespace: example
  syncPolicy:
    automated:
      prune: true
      selfHeal: true
    syncOptions:
      - CreateNamespace=true
```

When I apply this, it only applies the one of the random valueFiles and not all of them

How can I deploy multiple instances of the same helm chart with using different value files?

Thanks

Comment: Sounds like you want to use `ApplicationSet` rather than `Application`. What you wrote is to deploy 1 single app with the values of all 3 files combined.